# How generate pdf in rake task using cron job rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake-task, wicked-pdf

Hi i am using rails 3 and wicked pdf gem to generate pdf in my controllers.But now i want to

generate pdf in rake task which will run through cron jobs.After creating this PDF i will send

it in email.

```
   this is my normal controller method to generate pdf


    def generate_invoice_pdf
      begin
        @trunk_groups_orig = TrunkGroupSubscriber.all
        render :pdf => "GenerateInvoice", :layout => false, :template => "/accountings/generate_invoice_pdf"
     rescue => client
      puts client.inspect
     end
    end
```

But how i can generate pdf in rake task

Many many thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `pdfkit`  or `wicked_pdf` then you can try [this](http://iparamtech.blogspot.in/2011/09/generate-pdf-using-erb-or-haml-and.html),see if it works.

Updating code

```
class PdfInvoice
 def generate_invoice
  @trunk_groups_orig = TrunkGroupSubscriber.all
   content = File.read('#{Rails.root}/app/views/accountings/generate_invoice_pdf.erb')
   template = ERB.new(content) 
   # THis will generate html content 
   html_content = template.result(binding) 
   # now you have html content
   pdf= WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(html_content)
   # then save to a file
  save_path = Rails.root.join('pdfs','filename.pdf')
  File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file|
   file << pdf
  end
 end 
end

PdfInvoice.new.generate_pdf
#You can customize method based on your requirement,
```

Comment: in my case what i read from this i d'nt understand              content = File.read "#{Rails.root}/app/views/accountings/generate_invoice_pdf.html.erb"

Comment: make it erb and read it will read just erb now in your model,

Comment: problem in passing variables to template how?

Comment: i have this error and no pdf is saved anywhere                       No such file or directory - /home/kashif/rails_app/Peeredge-Customer-Portal/pdfs/filename.pdf

Comment: You have to customize and check it out wicked pdf doc how to render from string,do you have pdf directories in rails.root